# Object from sessionStorage not reactive in vuejs / vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, session-storage, vuejs3

I know this is a noob question but I can't figure it out despite looking through different posts. Please help.
I'm building a shopping cart with Vue and Vuex. I store the content of the cart in `sessionStorage` so that it persists if the user refreshes.

When the page loads, I am able to retrieve the cart from session and add it to vuex state but it doesn't reflect in the DOM until I add a new item to the cart. How can I solve this?

This is my code:
I check to see if there's any session in `beforeUpdate`:

```
beforeUpdate() {
  // this fires twice. why?
  let cart = this.store_slug + '_cart'
  found_cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(cart))
  if (found_cart) {
    this.$store.commit('restoreCart', found_cart)
  }
},
```

This is my `'restoreCart'` mutation:

```
restoreCart(state, found_cart) {
  state.cart.push(found_cart)
},
```

Comment: Why do you push the card into an array ? Is your application going to have more than 1 card simultaneously ?

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV this has solved one of the problems I was having (adding to cart was creating a new cart item instead of updating the existing one). I didn't realise I was pushing the "session" cart into the "state" cart. It is still not reactive though.

Comment: You mean that `state.cart = newObject` does not have any effect ?

Comment: ```state.cart = newObject``` i.e. ```state.cart = found_cart``` has an effect. I can see in the vuejs browser extension that the item is in the cart but when I navigate to my cart, the items are not displayed. However, if I add a new item to the cart, both the new and old items are then displayed.

Comment: Hey @IVOGELOV I added a subsequent function that used the items in cart after restoring it and it displays now. This has the same effect of $nextTick although I was unable to use $nextTick. Your solution worked if you'd like to post it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your current code is that you are trying to push the old cart into the current one as if it (the old cart) was a product item. You should actually assign the old cart to the new one

```js
restoreCart(state, found_cart) {
  state.cart = found_cart;
},
```

It depends on how you use your store to read the current cart contents but something like this will instantly update when you restore the old cart:

```html
<div v-for="item in $store.state.cart" :key="item.id">
{{ item.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: You missed out the ">" for the opening div tag